# How to get kubectl logs by setting yaml or other?

Tags: logging, yaml, kubectl, kubernetes-pod

I excuted the command *kubectl create -f data.yaml* to create a pod.
The yaml file likes below.

```
...
containers:
    - name: pod_test
      image: ubuntu:latest
      command: ["bash"]
      tty: true
...
...
```

Then, I copy the program to the pod and run it.
I can see the info the program print when in the pod,but I can't see the logs by *kubectl logs*.
How to set the yaml file for reading the logs by *kubectl logs*?

By the way, the program is just a golang program and print("hello wolrd").

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect the output to main process of the container.

```
 go run hello-world.go > /proc/1/fd/1
```

something like this

[image]